# SpringBoot - This localhost page can’t be found - Error (Jersey WebApp)

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jsp, jersey

I created simple Jersey web app using Spring boot but I keep getting this weird error:

This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8383/
HTTP ERROR 404

**POM.XML**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>logs</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>logs</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-mvc-jsp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>jersey-mvc-hello-world</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.8.v20160314</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**WEB.XML**

```
<web-app>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>Jersey</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.AppConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    
    <filter-mapping>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <filter-name>Jersey</filter-name>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**AppConfig.java**

```
package com.example.logs;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    
        
        public AppConfig() {
            packages("com.example.logs");
            property(JspMvcFeature.TEMPLATE_BASE_PATH, "/WEB-INF/jsp");
            register(JspMvcFeature.class);
        }
    }
```

**HomeController**

```
package com.example.logs;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.Viewable;

@Path("/")
public class HomeController {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Viewable index() {
        System.out.println("Test message!--------------------");
        Map<String, String> model = new HashMap<>();
        model.put("hello", "Hello");
        model.put("world", "World");
        return new Viewable("/index", model);
    }
}
```

**webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>${it.hello} ${it.world}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

It seems that I have everything, when I navigate to: http://localhost:8383/ my breakpoint stops at method in the HomeController, so that is linked properly. However after this function I'm getting this screen:

[image]

This is how my project structure looks like:

[image]

Do you see any problem here? I spent days trying to create simple Jersey App that will return some jsp but without any luck. If you have any idea why I'm getting this 404 screen please let me know. I read docs, read bunch of other articles but it seems that I did everything right..

**EDIT:** This is the error that I'm having when I start up the application, maybe it has something to do with this problem..

```
java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:209) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:383) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:318) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:282) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:233) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:83) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5219) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:473) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:206) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at com.example.logs.ApplicationMain.main(ApplicationMain.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor18.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\just.quest\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\hk2\2.6.1\hk2-utils.jar
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:53) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:38) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:198) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1843) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1198) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:701) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:240) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:171) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:347) ~[na:na]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
```

Comment: 1. Use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to build your executable archive. 2. Remove `@EnableWebMvc`. 3. Ditch your `web.xml` and 4. JSP generally only work in a WAR archive **not** a jar archive.

Comment: It's still the same: I deleted web.xml, removed @EnableWebMvc annotation, added spring-boot-maven-plugin dependency and executed mvn clean install, however it's still the same problem. Did I miss anything?

Comment: You seem to be missing a jar, and not sure how you are launching/building things.

Comment: I feel like I'm doing something incredibly stupid but this is what I did:

1.) Right click on pom.xml -> Run As -> Maven build.. (in goal section I add clean install) and Run
2.) Right click on the main class (@SpringBootApplication class) -> Debug as -> Java Application.

And this starts the application so when I navigate to: http://localhost:8383/  my breakpoints stops in the controller and after that I get that error.

Is my building / launching process wrong?

Comment: yes your running is wrong. As you should run the resulting war file. JSP are terrible and limited when using from an embedded container due to the loading of those files. So JSP only works with a packaging of war and as run as a war (or deployed). However your build is complaining about a missing/unreadable jar so not sure how that relates to this.

Comment: /JerseyJSP/target/jersey-mvc-hello-world.war - have war package now, however it's still the same for some reason. When I run this jersey-mvc-hello-world.war I'm getting same error as before.

Thanks for the suggestions, I'm out of ideas (and articles to read) :/